# How to show and hide a button inside recycleview with some debouncing using kotlin coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, coroutine, debouncing

[image: This is what i am trying to achieve]

The above is what I am trying to achieve .

My recycle view item has two buttons . Both are hidden by default . On click of the item view should show the buttons for 1 sec. After it must hide . if I tap on either of these buttons , the timer should be reset for another 1 sec . Something similar to a debounce in rx java.
Need to do it with Kotlin coroutines .

I was able to achieve the above using kotlin coroutines jobs .

My layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_count"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guideline_horizontal_top"
        android:text="x2"
        android:fontFamily="@font/gotham"
        android:textColor="@color/dark_blue"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_horizontal_top"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".20"/>
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/part_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guideline_horizontal_top"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:cardElevation="5dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        >
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >
            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/plus_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/transparent_dark_blue"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                android:insetTop="0dp"
                app:cornerRadius="0dp"
                android:text="ADD"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>
            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/minus_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/transparent_dark_blue"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                android:insetBottom="0dp"
                app:cornerRadius="0dp"
                android:text="REDUCE"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/partition_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                android:text="PART 1"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_blue"
                android:fontFamily="@font/gotham_thin_font"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/items_left"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Items left : "
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_blue"
                android:fontFamily="@font/gotham_thin_font"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                android:gravity="center"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/product_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/partition_text"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/items_left"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_blue"
                android:fontFamily="@font/gotham_thin_font"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:text="Product name here"
                />


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

My addapter

```
class PartitionRecycleAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<PartitionRecycleAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private var partitions: List<Selection<Partition>> = listOf()
    private val coroutineScope: CoroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)
    private var buttonManage: Job? = null

    fun update(partitions: List<Selection<Partition>>) {
        this.partitions = partitions
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }


    inner class ViewHolder(val binding: PartitionRecycleItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(partition: Selection<Partition>, position: Int) {
            binding.apply {
                partitionText.text = "Part ${partition.item.number}"
                productName.text = partition.item.productName
                val itemsLeftVar = partition.item.currentQty - partition.qty
                itemsLeft.text = "Items left : $itemsLeftVar"
                productCount.text = "X${partition.qty}"
                if (partition.qty > 0) {
                    productCount.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                } else {
                    productCount.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "bind: OUTER")

                val listener = View.OnClickListener { view ->

                    buttonManage?.cancel()

                    buttonManage = coroutineScope.launch {
                        Log.d(TAG, "bind: Coroutine started")
                        delay(1000)
                        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                            binding.plusButton.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                            binding.minusButton.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                            Log.d(TAG, "bind: Coroutine Ended")

                        }

                    }
                    if (view == partCard) {
                        binding.plusButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                        binding.minusButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE

                    }


                    if (view == plusButton) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "bind: PLUS")
                        if (itemsLeftVar > 0) {
                            partition.qty++
//                            notifyItemChanged(position)
                        }
                    }
                    if (view == minusButton) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "bind: MINUS")
                        if (partition.qty > 0) {
                            partition.qty--
//                            notifyItemChanged(position)
                        }
                    }


                }

                partCard.setOnClickListener(listener)
                plusButton.setOnClickListener(listener)
                minusButton.setOnClickListener(listener)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val binding = PartitionRecycleItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val partition = partitions[position]
        holder.bind(partition, position)

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return partitions.size
    }
}
```

**The problem is , when I add notifyItemChanged on my button click . Everything breaks. the button closes sometimes . sometimes not .**

please help..